# SQL UNIONs that use the WITH statement

Tags: sql, union

I have to run this query on 20 databases to produce one unified report.  I've done this before with a UNION.  Is there any way to reuse the WITH statement for each sub-query?  I am receiving an error saying that the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.  Could there be a better way of doing this?

```
WITH
DUPS (DocNum)
AS (
    SELECT DocNum
    FROM Akron.dbo.PWZ3
    INNER JOIN Akron.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = PWZ3.IdEntry
    WHERE T5.PmntDate = '3/10/2011'
    GROUP BY DocNum
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
)
SELECT PWZ3.IdEntry, PWZ3.DocNum, 'ARK' + PWZ3.CardCode, QUOTENAME(CardName,'"'), 
Convert(Decimal(10,2),PayAmount), Convert(Decimal(10,2),InvPayAmnt), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T5.PmntDate,101), NumAtCard, PymMeth, ObjType
FROM Akron.dbo.PWZ3 PWZ3
INNER JOIN DELAWARE.dbo.OPWZ T5 ON T5.IdNumber = PWZ3.IdEntry
LEFT JOIN Dups ON DUPS.DocNum = PWZ3.DocNum 
WHERE T5.PmntDate = '3/10/2011'
AND T5.Canceled = 'N' 
AND Checked = 'Y'
AND Dups.DocNum is null
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WITH` statement indicates that the query expressed within the `AS` clause is a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) (CTE).

If you're asking if you can write more than one query that uses a CTE, then the answer is no. The closest approximation would be creating an inline [table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

(The simple definition of an ordinary table-valued function versus an inline table-valued function is that the inline version is defined only as a query, much like a CTE; you can't do any procedural operations within the function, including declaring/assigning variables).

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
WITH stuff AS (
   ... some select 
) 
SELECT some_col
FROM some_table
  JOIN stuff ON ...
UNION ALL
SELECT other_col
FROM other_table
  JOIN stuff ON ...
```

Tested on PostgreSQL and Oracle